# trapping focus for a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, accessibility

I wanted to make modal dialog accessible . I added two hidden focusable elements

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dialog-start">Dialog Start </a>
  Some focussable Dialog Elements  
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dialog-end" onblur="onblurevent()">Dialog end</a>


function onblurevent(){
   document.getElementById("dialog-start").focus(); 
}
```

When ever dialog-end element blur event happens i tried to move focus to dialog-start element calling focus() method 
but  the focus is moving to address bar .dialog start and end anchor tags are hidden by using below style

```
#dialog-start{
  height:1px;
  left:-9999px; 
  overflow:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:1px;
}
```

Iam not sure if anchor styles are the reason  or  is the only way to make sure focus is inside the dialog is to get list of focusable elments and call focus() method in a keydown event handler on container.

Comment: where is the code for the onblurevent() call? It would be useful to have that.

Comment: Thanks for helping .I included onblurevent() code and also styles i used for anchor tag .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs because you don't handle your keydown event. When you pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> on last link browser automatically switches focus to address bar. So you just need to `preventDefault()` default browser behavior if <kbd>Tab</kbd> pressed.

The following code will work:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var firstAnchor = document.getElementById("dialog-start"),
        lastAnchor = document.getElementById("dialog-end");

    function keydownHandler(e) {
        var evt = e || window.event;
        var keyCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
        if(keyCode === 9) { // TAB pressed
            if(evt.preventDefault) evt.preventDefault();
            else evt.returnValue = false;
            firstAnchor.focus();
        }
    }

    if(lastAnchor.addEventListener) lastAnchor.addEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler, false);
    else if(lastAnchor.attachEvent) lastAnchor.attachEvent('onkeydown', keydownHandler);
}
```

(note that you dont need `onblurevent` function anymore)

Comment: Thanks a lot !! Its working fine in one direction .if i use shift-tab to move backwards its not working  .

Comment: You should add `onfocus` handler for first link which will immediately move focus to first dialog input, so there'll be no way to use <kbd>shift<kbd/>+<kbd>tab</kbd> on first link.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //set focus on first field in Bootstrap modal when loaded
    $("#yourModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('#yourField').focus();
    });
});
```